# How to update pg's json array data by some key's value directly?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

Something looks so simple, but so difficut to use it. In my pg functions, I frequently use json data to store array data.

Just look my json data below:

```
[
    {
        "id":5,
        "name":"John",
        "sex":"male"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "name":"Alice",
        "sex":"female"
    },
    {
        "id":6,
        "name":"Jack",
        "sex":"male"
    }
]
```

For example, I want to modify the array's suboject's some value, that is, **I just want to modify the "name" to "Tom" where the "id" is 5**, how to solve it directly?

If I use jsonb_set function, you know the jsonb_set function doesn't support condition, I should first know the index of array's suboject, just as

```
jsonb_set(myjsonb,'{0,name}','Tome')
```

**But I Don't Know The Index Firstly, I Just Know The Element Object's Some Key's Value**.

Of cource, I can first put the subobject into one table, that looks so complex, just like below:

```
select 
  fserial-1 into myindex
from jsonb_array_elements(myjson) with ordinality vids(frow ,fserial)
where cast(frow->>'id' as bigint)=5;
```

I think perhaps I could use jsonb_set and jsonpath together to solve it directly, but I viewed the [pg's documention](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html), I could not find a right way.

PG supplied so many Path Operators And Methods for json array, include .size() and soso, Why not supply a .index() method?  And why the jsonb_set function support condition?

Can you give me some simple way to solve this problem directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unnest, modify and reaggregate:

```
select json_agg(
    case when obj ->> 'id' = '5' 
        then obj - 'name' || '{"name": "Tom"}'::jsonb
        else obj
    end
    order by rn
) as newjson
from jsonb_array_elements(myjson) with ordinality x(obj, rn)
```